# How to compare 2 QImages

Tags: qt, qimage

**How can we compare** two [QImage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html)s ?

I have 2 `QImage`s as below with some actual data in it:

```
QImage image_1;  
QImage image_2;
```

If I do a `if(image_1 == image_2)` & this returns `true` then does it mean the that the 2 `QImage`s are pixel to pixel same?

Or does it mean that they are equal in sizes?
Or does it mean something completely different?

**Note:**
My requirement is to confirm that the `QImage`s are pixel to pixel same.
*Please suggest if there is a way to do that kindo of comparasion*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I do a if(image_1 == image_2) & this returns true then does it mean
>   the that the 2 QImages are pixel to pixel same?

Yes, same pixels: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#operator-eq-eq

We have equal operator described as:

> bool QImage::operator==(const QImage &image) const Returns true if
>   this image and the given image have the same contents; otherwise
>   returns false.
>
> The comparison can be slow, unless there is some obvious difference
>   (e.g. different size or format), in which case the function will
>   return quickly.